# Is there a maximal translation-invariant extension of Lebesgue measure?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

(Cross posted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999840/is-there-a-maximal-translation-invariant-extension-of-lebesgue-measure).)

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/extension-of-the-lebesgue-measurable-sets) shows that there are translation-invariant extensions of Lebesgue measure.

> Are there *maximal* translation-invariant extensions of Lebesgue measure (in ZFC)? If so, is there more than one?

To be more precise, let $\mathcal L$ be the sigma-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. By the linked post, there exists $A \subset [0,1]$ such that $A \notin \mathcal L$ and there exists a translation-invariant measure $\mu'$ on $\sigma(\mathcal L \cup \{A\})$ that extends the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal L$. My question is:

> Is there a sigma-algebra $\mathcal L' \supset \mathcal L$ and a measure $\mu'$ on $\mathcal L'$ such that $\mu'$ is a translation-invariant extension of Lebesgue measure and if $A \not \in \mathcal L'$, then there is no translation-invariant extension of $\mu'$ to $\sigma(\mathcal L' \cup \{A\})$? If such an $\mathcal L'$ exists, is it unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. This is the main result of "Extensions of invariant measures on Euclidean spaces" by Ciesielski and Pelc.

Comment: Cool paper, thanks!

Comment: Is there a finitely additive isomery invariant extension of Lebesgue measure(in $\mathbb{R}^d$) to a maximal sigma algebra?

Comment: @VivaanDaga Yes, by Zorn's lemma.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer We get an algebra by Zorn's lemma, not a sigma algebra unless I am missing something.

Comment: Or is that an open problem?(It feels like a hard question)

Comment: @VivaanDaga Sorry, I hadn't seen the "sigma" in your question. A finitely additive measure $\mu$ with those properties is maximal iff its domain is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})^d,$ so there is such an extension iff $d \le 2.$ Section 2 of the Ciesielski/Pelc paper constructs a partition $\mathbb{R}^d=\bigcup_{k<\omega} N_k$ such that for any $k$ and isometries $\langle g_m \rangle,$ there are uncountably many disjoint isometric copies of $\bigcup_{m<\omega} g_m ``(N_k).$ Fix $S \subset \mathbb{R}^d.$ By maximality of $\mu,$ we have $\mu(S \cap N_k)=0,$ so $S$ is in the domain of $\mu.$